# Howto save HashSet<String> to .txt?

Tags: java, string, file-io, set, hashset

I want to store the HashSet to the server directory.
But i'm now only been able to store it in .bin files.
But how do I print all the Key's in the HashSet to a .txt file?

```
static Set<String> MapLocation = new HashSet<String>();

    try {
        SLAPI.save(MapLocation, "MapLocation.bin");
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

public static void save(Object obj, String path) throws Exception {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
            path));
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
}
```

Comment: Why not just iterating through the set and writing all strings to file? Also, what type of object is SLAPI?

Comment: what do you mean by keys in a HashSet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// check IOException in method signature
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
Iterator it = MapLocation.iterator(); // why capital "M"?
while(it.hasNext()) {
    out.write(it.next());
    out.newLine();
}
out.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

This will save the strings to a UTF-8 text file:

```
public static void save(Set<String> obj, String path) throws Exception {
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), "UTF-8"));
        for (String s : obj) {
            pw.println(s);
        }
        pw.flush();
    } finally {
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Specifically choosing UTF-8 is desirable because otherwise it will use whatever setting the operating system uses as its default, which will give you compatibility headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public static void toTextFile(String fileName, Set<String> set){
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(fileName, charset))) {
        for(String content: set){
            writer.println(content);
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This code is written using the try-with-resource construct introduced in Java 7. But the idea would remain the same for other versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that avoids a line break at the end of the file:

```
private static void store(Set<String> sourceSet, String targetFileName) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String setElement : sourceSet)
    {
        stringBuilder.append(setElement);
        stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    String setString = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
    byte[] setBytes = setString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Files.write(Paths.get(targetFileName), setBytes);
}
```